# Error occurs during Java: (wrong-type-argument stringp (require . info))

Tags: org-mode, java

EDIT: Error is not present with Emacs 26.3. I will revist when Emacs 27 becomes a release.

Emacs 27.0.50

This error occurs when I load a `.java` file or read java code in an `org-mode` src block. How may I prevent this error from occuring? Thank you. :)

[image: Screenshot of error]

My `jvm.el` config might be the culprit.

```
;;; package --- Summary:
;;; Commentary:
;;; JVM Languages & Support
;;;; Java
;;;; https://blog.jmibanez.com/2019/03/31/emacs-as-java-ide-revisited.html
(use-package lsp-java
  :after lsp
  :config
  (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'lsp)
  (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
  (require 'dap-java))
;;;; Kotlin
;;;; Groovy & Gradle
(use-package groovy-mode)

;;;; Scala
(use-package scala-mode)
;;;; Clojure
(use-package cider
  :after lsp
  :init
  (setq lsp-enable-indentation nil)
  (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(clojure-mode . "clojure-mode"))
  :config
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'lsp)
  (add-hook 'clojurec-mode-hook 'lsp)
  (add-hook 'clojurescript-mode-hook 'lsp))
(use-package cider-hydra)

;;;; Add Java to Org-babel
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
   (append org-babel-load-languages
           '((java . t))))

;;;; Maven
(setq nxml-child-indent 4)

(provide 'jvm)
;;; jvm.el ends here
```

Comment: That's very weird.  You have a badly-formed `load-history`.  The car of each element should be a string (the path to the library), and evidentially here you've ended up with a `(require . info)` element in that position.  I can't explain that, but maybe this still helps a little.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?  This looks like https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/flnp5v/wrongtypeargument_stringp_require_orgagenda_in/ which suggests you're likewise using an unstable build, but didn't say so in your question.  It's always very useful information to include version details in a question, but *especially* so when you're not using a stable release.

Comment: @phils I have downgraded to Emacs 26.3 and the error is no longer present. I forgot why I upgraded to Emacs 27. I think it was because it has native JSON, but I do not recall. I will revisit this once Emacs 27 because a stable release.

Thank you! :)